# Use decorator to connect to a postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working on a program to store my picture meta data and thumbnails into a postgres database using python and psycopg2. In the example I have defined a class `MyDbase` with methods to create a table, store a value and load a value. Each of these methods needs to connect to the database and a cursor object to execute sql commands. To avoid repetition of code to make the connection and get the cursor I have made a sub class `DbDecorators` with a decorator `connect`.

My question: is this a proper way to handle this and specifically using the with statement and passing the cursor to the Dbase method (`func`) inside the wrapper?

```
from functools import wraps
import psycopg2


class MyDbase:
    ''' example using a decorator to connect to a dbase
    '''
    table_name = 'my_table'

    class DbDecorators:
        host = 'localhost'
        db_user = 'db_tester'
        db_user_pw = 'db_tester_pw'
        database = 'my_database'

        @classmethod
        def connect(cls, func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                connect_string = f'host=\'{cls.host}\' dbname=\'{cls.database}\''\
                                 f'user=\'{cls.db_user}\' password=\'{cls.db_user_pw}\''
                result = None
                try:
                    with psycopg2.connect(connect_string) as connection:
                        cursor = connection.cursor()
                        result = func(*args, cursor, **kwargs)

                except psycopg2.Error as error:
                    print(f'error while connect to PostgreSQL {cls.database}: '
                          f'{error}')

                finally:
                    if connection:
                        cursor.close()
                        connection.close()
                        print(f'PostgreSQL connection to {cls.database} is closed')
                return result
            return wrapper

        @staticmethod
        def get_cursor(cursor):
            if cursor:
                return cursor

            else:
                print(f'no connection to database')
                raise()


    @classmethod
    @DbDecorators.connect
    def create_table(cls, *args):
        cursor = cls.DbDecorators().get_cursor(*args)

        sql_string = f'CREATE TABLE {cls.table_name} '\
                     f'(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30));'

        print(sql_string)
        cursor.execute(sql_string)

    @classmethod
    @DbDecorators.connect
    def store_value(cls, name, *args):
        cursor = cls.DbDecorators().get_cursor(*args)

        sql_string = f'INSERT INTO {cls.table_name} (name) VALUES (%s);'
        print(sql_string)
        cursor.execute(sql_string, (name,))

    @classmethod
    @DbDecorators.connect
    def load_value(cls, _id, *args):
        cursor = cls.DbDecorators().get_cursor(*args)

        sql_string = f'SELECT * FROM {cls.table_name} where id = \'{_id}\';'
        print(sql_string)
        cursor.execute(sql_string)
        db_row = cursor.fetchone()

        return db_row


def test():
    my_db = MyDbase()
    my_db.create_table()
    my_db.store_value('John Dean')
    db_row = my_db.load_value(1)
    print(f'id: {db_row[0]}, name: {db_row[1]}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

probably I did not get your request correctly. Why you need decorator but don't use context manager? Like define db client in any file where from you can import it later and then use it in context manager –

```
from psycopg2 import SomeDataBase  

db = SomeDataBase(credentials)

def create_table(table_name):
        with db:

            sql_string = f'CREATE TABLE {table_name} '\
                     f'(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30));'

            db.cursor.execute(sql_string)
```

Comment: I see what you mean. The disadvantage is that error handling is decentralized, i.e. I need to implement a try except loop for each db.cursor.execute() to catch an error otherwise the program will halt rather than log the issue. Also I am still not clear if db.cursor.close() needs to be called ??

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen I got you point about error handling. Using context manager cursor.close() will be called automatically still

Answer (score 0):

Using a context manager will not close the connection, only the cursor. So using the decorator pattern actually makes more sense here. More info on the context manager: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html (scroll down to the "with statement" section.)